# Why am i getting this "HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-1' failed to execute: No attribute named"

Tags: scala, csv, gatling

Im trying to create my first Gatling performance test and am getting this error and I cant work out why.

The error

```
HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-1' failed to execute: No attribute named 'anumber' is defined
```

This is my code

```
package sweetpackage

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class OneClassToRuleThemAll extends Simulation {

  object SubmitGet {

    val feeder = csv("numbers.csv")

    val GetAPI = exec(
      http("/v0/playa/palyaid")
        .get("/services/playas/v0/playa/${anumber}")
    )
  }
  
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://playassite")
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Site","same-origin")
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode","cors") 
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest","empty")
    .acceptHeader("application/json")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.9")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.38")

  val users = scenario("KingPins").exec(SubmitGet.GetAPI)

  setUp(
    users.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

My test data file is a csv file named `numbers.csv` with UTF-8 encoding. I created the file in MS Excel

```
anumber
500100
```

Comment: So I changed the GetAPI to this and it worked but i don't understand why `   def GetAPI() = {
      repeat(1) {
        feed(csvFeeder)
          .exec(http("Get plays")
          .get("services/playa/v0/playa/${anumber}")
          .check(status.is(200)))
          .pause(1)
      } 
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the sample you provided did you add a `feed` action in your scenario to actually read from your feeder. You only did so in your comment. So the data injected injected in your virtual users.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. It have a few typos though

```
package sweetpackage

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class OneClassToRuleThemAll extends Simulation {

  object SubmitGet {

    val feeder = csv("numbers.csv")

    def GetAPI() = { repeat(1) 
      { feed(csvFeeder) 
        .exec(http("Get plays") 
        .get("services/playa/v0/playa/${anumber}") 
        .check(status.is(200))) .pause(1) 
      }
    }
  }
  
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://playassite")
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Site","same-origin")
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode","cors") 
    .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest","empty")
    .acceptHeader("application/json")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.9")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.38")

  val users = scenario("KingPins").exec(SubmitGet.GetAPI)

  setUp(
    users.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```